# How to Enforce Dark Mode on Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

All extensions are disabled on Chrome Web Store, for security reason I believe... However, I like to browse for extensions a lot and I want to save my eyes.

Is there a way to tweak some Chrome settings so that I can use [some dark mode extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode/dmghijelimhndkbmpgbldicpogfkceaj) on the web store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Chrome Canary, you can [Force Dark Mode for Web Contents using a new flag](https://mspoweruser.com/new-chrome-flag-lets-you-force-dark-mode-on-any-website/)

Answer (score 3):

[wada](https://superuser.com/users/1086679/wada)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1486834/116475) now works with Google Chrome.

chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark](https://chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark) is really useful, but it will enable **dark mode** globally ie. for all other websites as well leaving no need for (the excellent) [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) extension :-)

See screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIpR2.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).